# Getting Error 3024 file not found for a mystery file not even used by the program? (dbo.mdb)

Tags: ms-access, vba

One user reported getting error:

> `3024 Could not find file ...\user\path\to\My Documents\dbo.mdb`

But *there is no file of this name needed nor referenced nor coded, nothing.*  I have no clue as to why the error would say this.

The error occurred somewhere during these three steps:

```
If IsLoaded("ApptDetails") Then
    strStep = "Closing Appt Details Form"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "ApptDetails"
End If
If IsLoaded("NewClientDetails") Then
    strStep = "Closing New Client Details Form"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "NewClientDetails"
End If
If iFormEdit = 1 Then
    strStep = "Opening Appt Details Form, form Edit = " & iFormEdit
    DoCmd.OpenForm "ApptDetails", acNormal, , , iFormEdit, , strOpenArgs
Else
    strStep = "Opening New Client Details Form, form Edit = " & iFormEdit
    DoCmd.OpenForm "NewClientDetails", acNormal, , , , , strOpenArgs
End If
```

Background:

Environment is Access 2010 on Windows 7 inside company network, back end SQL 2012 within the network.

Each user has a copy of the Access FE on their desktop and they get a fresh copy of the master each time they log in.  This improved performance greatly.  This database is heavily used.

My database was originally written in 2008, and has been updated as needed.  Problems started being reported in July by multiple users.  Prior update to database design was in Dec 2016.  I upgraded the code to ADO and made fixes to syntax that I could find.  Installed update 3 weeks ago, been running fine until today.

Any brilliant ideas out there would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since none of that code seems to be directly doing DB work, is there any code run when the forms are being opened, and could be where the error originates? Can you reproduce this in the debugger?

Answer (score 0):

it could be one of your SQL that is calling wrong table.

i think that in access the dots in the SQL table names are renamed to underline or so.

try to identify when happends (after click, or on load, or something) and recheck your querys.

good luck

Comment: I improved the error reporting and I'm waiting for a new error to pop in. The users use this function many times per day.  It took weeks for this error since my last update to the Access file.  So it must be more involved than just calling the wrong table.